# QScrollArea derivative is empty if it's created from an .ui file

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

Consider following simple example:

**Area.hh**

```
#pragma once

class Area;

#include <QScrollArea>

class Area : public QScrollArea {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Area (QWidget *_parent = 0);
};
```

**Area.cc**

```
#include "main.hh"
#include "Area.hh"

#include <QLabel>

Area::Area (QWidget *_parent) :
    QScrollArea (_parent)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel ("Show me please");
    setWidget (label);
}
```

This scroll area should show a label inside it. And it does so well if you just create an Area object and show it like this:

```
Area *area = new Area();
area->show();
```

However, if you add a `QScrollArea` with Qt Creator and promote it to `Area` class, then it shows nothing inside and there are no scrollbars. What can I do to show it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Designer adds an empty widget inside the `QScrollArea`, overwriting yours.

To prevent that, use a base `QWidget` instead of a `QScrollArea`, and promote that widget to an `Area` class. Qt's Ui compiler won't considered it to be a `QScrollArea`, so it won't generate a call to `setWidget` anymore.